# Create a more realistic typewriting-effect, remove/add chars randomly

Tags: javascript, random, replace, effects, slice

I try to create a more realistic typewriting, which makes typing errors and corrects them by removing/adding chars.

Yet, I made a simple solution which can add and remove chars via `slice`. But I don't know how to implement the misstyping-feature.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
var str = 'Foo bar is not equal to bar foo.';
var len = str.length;

var elem = document.body;

var rem = len;
var add = 0;

(function type(){
  if(!rem || add === len) return;

  // write
  elem.innerHTML = str.slice(0, ++add);

  // remove
  // elem.innerHTML = str.slice(0, --rem);

  setTimeout(type, 100);
}());
```

http://jsbin.com/upufaf/6/edit

Any ideas or already finished solutions how to get this to work?

BTW: There's already something called [*realistic typewriter*](https://github.com/fardjad/realistic-typewriter.js), however I think this solution is a bit too bloated for that simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = 'Foo bar is not equal to bar foo.' ;
var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' ;
var pos = 0 ;
var tmpStr = '' ;
var doBackspace = false ;
function startTyping (str) {

    if(doBackspace) {
        tmpStr = tmpStr.slice(0,tmpStr.length-1);
        doBackspace = false ;
    } else {

        if(Math.ceil((Math.random()*100)) < 80) {
            tmpStr += str[pos] ;
            pos++ ;

        } else {
            tmpStr += alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random()*(alphabet.length))] ;
            doBackspace = true ;
        }
    }   
    $('body').html(tmpStr) ;

    if(pos < str.length) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            startTyping(str)
        }, 300) ;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    startTyping(str) ;
});
```

Can change interval 300 to higher value to reduce typing speed, also add characters to alphabet to increase number of possible mistaken chars, 80 to lower value to increase chance for a mistake